# Where can blacksmith manuals be found in mabinogi?

Tags: mabinogi

I've played Mabinogi for a while and have been going back and forth between blacksmithing and close combat skills. I'm having trouble with blacksmithing though because I've constantly been doing part time jobs but it doesn't seem to be helping.  I'm at rank C but all Edern gives are jobs for sickles or something low and I get nowhere.  All the guides I read only suggests what to make but doesn't actually say where to get the manuals.  Would anyone happen to know where to get manuals such as gauntlets in order to continue ranking up blacksmithing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[List of all blacksmith items and where to get the manual](http://wiki.mabinogiworld.com/view/Blacksmith_List). This describes what materials you need per attempt, what materials you need for the finishing, the cost of a manual, where to get a manual and the experience gained upon producing one of the items.